# selenium java ant run

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm aware of `run_in_parallel` and `run_in_sequence` with Ruby - Selenium.

How can we run selenium tests using **JAVA** in `parallel` or `sequence` using **ant run** command?